# ListView shows only one item

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I am trying to display Json in a ListView. I am using `Map` to retrieve the values. Only the first item is displayed in the list. **getCount()** in `BaseAdapter` returns size as 1 everytime even there are more than one values in `Map`.

**MyContactAdapter2 .java**

```
public class MyContactAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
        List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
        Context context;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;


        // Constructors
        public MyContactAdapter2(Context context, List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> objects) {

            this.context = context;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            contactList = objects;
        }

        public MyContactAdapter2() {
            System.out.println("hai");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int count = contactList.size();
            System.out.println("Count size" + count);
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, List<EffectList>> getItem(int position) {
            return contactList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            System.out.println(10);


            final MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder vh;
            if (convertView == null) {
                View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view, parent, false);
                vh = MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
                view.setTag(vh);

            } else {
                vh = (MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }





            for (Map<String, List<EffectList>> map : contactList) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<EffectList>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    Object value = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("key :" + key + "value :" + value);

                        EffectList item = getItem(position).get(key).get(0);

                        vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());
                        vh.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsName());

                }
            }


            return vh.rootView;
        }


        private static class ViewHolder {
            public final RelativeLayout rootView;
            public final ImageView imageView;
            public final TextView textViewName;
            public final TextView textViewEmail;

            private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewEmail) {
                this.rootView = rootView;
                this.imageView = imageView;
                this.textViewName = textViewName;
                this.textViewEmail = textViewEmail;
            }

            public static MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
                return new MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder(rootView, imageView, textViewName, textViewEmail);
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong in iterating the Map?

Here is the Json I am trying to parse.

```
{
"effect_list": [{
      "1":[  
         {  
            "effects_id":"1",
            "effects_name":"Band 1"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"2",
            "effects_name":"Band 2"
         }


      ],
      "2": [ 
         {  
            "effects_id":"4",
            "effects_name":"Background Blur"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"5",
            "effects_name":"Blemish Removal"
         }
      ] 
   }]
}
```

I want to display 1(0) and 2(0). Only 1(0) **("effects_id":"1")** is displaying in `ListView`

**Why is my getCount() size always 1 even it has more than one value?**

Comment: why you are making "1" and "2" array differently? when there is a  "effects_id" and "effects_name" same keys in both

Comment: but the values are different. I want to display the values

Comment: I know values will always be different. I think you should well maintain your json

Comment: post the code when you parse json and set to adapter. getCount() size always 1 => you are wrong when you parse json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
public class MyContactAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
    List<EffectList> contacts;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    // Constructors
    public MyContactAdapter2(Context context, List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> objects) {

    this.context = context;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, List<EffectList>> map = objects.get(0);
    Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
    Iterator<String> iterator = keySet.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        this.contacts.addAll(map.get(iterator.next()));
    }
}

    public MyContactAdapter2() {
        System.out.println("hai");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = contacts.size();
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public EffectList getItem(int position) {
        return contacts.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        System.out.println(10);


        final MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view, parent, false);
            vh = MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
            view.setTag(vh);

        } else {
            vh = (MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
            EffectList item = getItem(position);

            vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());
            vh.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsName());


        return vh.rootView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final RelativeLayout rootView;
        public final ImageView imageView;
        public final TextView textViewName;
        public final TextView textViewEmail;

        private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewEmail) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
            this.imageView = imageView;
            this.textViewName = textViewName;
            this.textViewEmail = textViewEmail;
        }

        public static MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
            return new MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder(rootView, imageView, textViewName, textViewEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting **OutOfMemoryError**

Comment: changed constructor

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked!

Comment: If I want to display only the values of "1", how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is batter way to add in list

```
    ArrayList<EffectList> data = new ArrayList<>();


     for (Map<String, List<EffectList>> map : contactList) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, List<EffectList>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        String key = entry.getKey();
                        List<EffectList> value = entry.getValue();
                        data.addAll(value);
                    }
                }

MyContactAdapter2  mAdpter = new MyContactAdapter2(this,data);
list.setAdapter(mAdpter);
```

And Then use that `data` list in Adapter

```
public class MyContactAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<EffectList> contactList;
        Context context;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;


        // Constructors
        public MyContactAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<EffectList> data ) {

            this.context = context;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            contactList = data ;
        }

        public MyContactAdapter2() {
            System.out.println("hai");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int count = contactList.size();
            System.out.println("Count size" + count);
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public EffectList getItem(int position) {
            return contactList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            System.out.println(10);


            final MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder vh;
            if (convertView == null) {
                View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view, parent, false);
                vh = MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
                view.setTag(vh);

            } else {
                vh = (MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

                        EffectList item = getItem(position);

                        vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());
                        vh.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsName());



            return vh.rootView;
        }
```

Comment: where should i iterate the map? I am getting error if i iterate it inside getview()

Comment: I edited code.. This need to call before adapter set to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your list view displays only one item because you have only one item. `effect_list` has only one element:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "effects_id": "1",
      "effects_name": "Band 1"
    },
    {
      "effects_id": "2",
      "effects_name": "Band 2"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "effects_id": "4",
      "effects_name": "Background Blur"
    },
    {
      "effects_id": "5",
      "effects_name": "Blemish Removal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your **json** like following and use accordingly.

```html
{
"effect_list": [
     
         {  
            "effects_id":"1",
            "effects_name":"Band 1"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"2",
            "effects_name":"Band 2"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"4",
            "effects_name":"Background Blur"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"5",
            "effects_name":"Blemish Removal"
         }
     
   ]
}
```

You can go through **effect_list.size** and can fetch each and every value

Comment: but those "1" and "2" are dynamic objects.